# How to get value of checkbox from table cell and submit as form

Tags: jquery, html

My question is how to get table cell element and append it form.

```js
function submitTable(url) {
    form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = 'POST';
    form.action = url;

    /*
     HOW TO FIND ALL SELECTED CHECKBOX HERE
    */
    
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">COL1</th>
            <th scope="col">COL2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="1">
                <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1[]" value="something">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" value="something">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td id="2">
                <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1[]" value="something">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" value="something">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="3">
                <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1[]" value="something">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" value="something">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td id="4">
                <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1[]" value="something">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" value="something">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="MYFORM" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

**how to find specific cell on click** and **on cell click check both the checkbox**, and when click the button, 
read all cells and get **checked checkbox value as array** and **submit as form**

I want when I click on cell not individual checkbox, when clicked on cell check both checkbox using jquery. Then, after selecting cells has been done, upon button `id="MYFORM"` click I want to find all the checked checkboxes and submit them as a generated form.

Comment: Please post more code. Where is submitRowAsForm() triggered? I do not see any IDs, except "MYFORM".

Comment: @Bernhard submitRowAsForm() is function from my previous code. I wanted to explain the concept of my expected output. I want when i click on cell not individual checkbox, when click on cell check both checkbox. Then after i am done selecting cells, i want to upon button (id="MYFORM") click find all the checked checkboxes and submit as form.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Is there a problem having `form` wrap your table?

Comment: @rt-jar Yes, cannot have form inside table

Comment: How do i get cell value or id when i click on table? Most other question discuss get row id which is not what i want. i want to get cell id not row id. How jquery will find which cell i clicked

Comment: It's not clear enough what you are trying to send, i.e. how the rows are selected. There are 2 checkboxes on each row. An arbitrary number of them can be selected.

Comment: @quasimodos-clone I just updated my question. I added id to td's and remove jquery since maybe its not related. Its like this, since table has tr and td, i want on td click find its id, then by using this td id check the two checkboxes. And next when click on submit button, get all checked checkboxes and submit as form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append all checked checkboxes, just use specify the appropriate collection as query selector:

```
function submitTable(url)
{
  let form = document.createElement('form');
  form.setAttribute('action', url);
  $("#my-table>tbody input[type=checkbox]:checked").clone().appendTo(form);

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

Note that your current naming can not be distinguished. Generate names like `name="checkbox1[1]"` specifying an explicit index.

You can select all checkboxes of a table row by

```
  $('#my-table>tbody>tr').click(function(ev)
  {
    if(ev.target.tagName !== 'INPUT')
      $(this).find('>td input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
  })
```

Comment: You table needs some id, here `id="my-table"`

Comment: Thanks, U answered one part of my question. How do i get td id and using that id select both the checkbox?

Comment: Your code has changed, there haven't been ids before.

Comment: Yes, i mentioned in comments earlier. i updated my code

Comment: Is this correct? $("#mytable").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each().clone().appendTo(form);

Comment: Why would you want to split the selectors? Further more we want only inputs which are children of the table.